# What is this exception?

Tags: .net, exception, com, interop

I am getting this exception while reading the shapes in excel sheet in c#:
on code line of

```
if (worksheet.Shapes.Count >= iCurrentRowIndex)
{ }
```

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'.
>   This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM
>   component for the interface with IID
>   '{000208D8-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
>   failed due to the following error: The
>   application called an interface that
>   was marshalled for a different thread.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).

Edited:

This application locally running perfect but when i deploy it on IIS , it throws exception. What should the reason? I use code for thread as

```
string strImageSavedPath = string.Empty;
ThreadStart cbThreadStater = delegate { strImageSavedPath =  CopyToClipBoard(worksheet, (int)iRowindex, strApplicationPath); };
Thread thrd = new Thread(cbThreadStater);
thrd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thrd.Start();
thrd.Join();
```

Where `CopyToClipBoard` method reads the image of supplied row index, saves the image in file system and return the path.

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   Message="Unable to cast
>   COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208D8-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: The application called an interface that was
>   marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))."   Source="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
>   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.get_Shapes()
>          at KGD6ExcelReader.ExcelManager.CopyToClipBoard(Worksheet worksheet, Int32 iRowindex, String strApplicationPath) in
>   D:\ParallelMinds\Shared\KGD6ExcelReader\KGD6ExcelReader\ExcelManager.cs:line
>   522
>          at KGD6ExcelReader.ExcelManager.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0()
>   in
>   D:\ParallelMinds\Shared\KGD6ExcelReader\KGD6ExcelReader\ExcelManager.cs:line
>   376
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Office automation objects from IIS is *not recommended* and *not supported.* So the fact that your app runs successfully locally, and unsuccessfully on IIS, is not entirely unexpected.

> [Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

That doesn't mean you can't try, but make sure you understand everything in the "[Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)" support article before you proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Is the code running on a background thread? If so, you need to set the ApartmentState for the thread to STA - you'll have to new up an actual Thread to do this and call the SetApartmentState method.

[more on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The COM interface reference (probably worksheet) that you are trying to use is for a proxy that is in a different appartment to the current thread. See [link text](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172314).

Try marshalling the reference to the current thread.

Comment: When its running locally, is that also under IIS? Or the Visual Studio integrated web server? Could you post the cross-thread marshaling code?